# Win32 API for Deleting User Profile?

Tags: winapi, windows-8, microsoft-metro, user-profile

One way of deleting the user profile is to delete the user from the ProfilesList registry key and to delete the user folder from the users directory.

On Windows 8 though this does not seem sufficient. There seems to be some data that is present in HKLM related to the user too. One such example is HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\'UserSid'.

Hence i'm looking for an API (Win32 SDK), that would delete all the filesystem and registry entries related to the User Profile?

Comment: [NetUserDel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370651.aspx).